# How to decline a request in Hellosign eSignature API using node endpoint?

Tags: node.js, hellosign-api

Is there any way to decline Hellosign's embedded signature request using the node.js endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

This is Hazem from HelloSign API Support.

Kindly note that ability to decline a request using the Node.js SDK is not available at this moment. That said, you can cancel a request using the "[Cancel Incomplete Signature Request" endpoint](https://app.hellosign.com/api/reference#cancel_incomplete_signature_request):

*Note:
To be eligible for cancelation, a signature request must have been sent successfully, must not yet have been signed by all signers, and you must either be the sender or own the API app under which it was sent. A partially signed signature request can be canceled.*

```
const hellosign = require('hellosign-sdk')({ key: 'API_KEY' });
hellosign.signatureRequest.cancel(signatureRequestId); 
// No local callback will fire. See the general description for the Cancel // Incomplete Signature Request endpoint for more information.
```

I hope this help clear things up for you! Feel free to email us at apisupport@hellosign.com if you have any other questions or concerns.